# i need hindi support in mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

```
var $link = $("#frametest").contents().find(".eod-topbox").find('a');
var variable2= $("#frametest").contents().find(".eod-topbox").find("h3").find(".hidetitle").html();
var variable1= $link.attr('href');
$.post('insert.php', {variable1: link_address, variable2: heading},
function(data){$("#message").html(data);});
alert(variable2);
alert(variable1);
```

In this script, `alert` are showing hindi text properly and showing link also. But when I try to save this `variable2` to the database, it saves something like this

```
à¤•à¤¾à¤‚à¤—à¥à¤°à¥‡à¤¸ à¤¸à¥‡ à¤¬à¤¢à¤¼à¤¤à¥€ AA...
```

in the message `div` hindi text is displaying properly and when I just copy hindi text to database manually there is no problem.
Please help somebody.

Comment: Where is the code, where you are saving to the database?

Comment: try converting the string to UTF-8 before saving to database.

Comment: Make sure the whole development chain from *Front* to *Back-end* are all using the *same* Charsets.

Comment: my code is on localhost and it is saving in mysql properly but i am not getting hindi font in table

Comment: What collation did you use for your table? Also try to use `set names 'utf8'` before saving to your DB.

Comment: You're using mismatched character sets.  Everything should be done in UTF8 (database, scripts, etc)

Comment: `$db->query("set names 'utf8'");` then do your insert.

Comment: if only one column is in utf-8 is there any problem ?

Comment: The database may be UTF8 but the connection might not be (set names 'utf8') or the PHP script might not be UTF8 encoded or the form submissions may not be UTF8 encoded. It's vitally important you use the same charset throughout.

Comment: thanks to everbody. i am on the seventh cloud :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's what I usually do in my connection file:

```
$db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

if ($db->connect_errno) {

    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $db->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$db->query("set names 'utf8'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your database column Collation should be `utf8_unicode_ci`

and place this code top of the PHP page

```
mysqli_set_charset ($con, "utf8");
```

and place

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

in your html header